# memory leak in xamarin in app purchase

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, xamarin

So I have been trying to setup in app purchase within my application and encountered a problem which I don't know how to solve. Im working with xamarin, and I followed their [In app purchase guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/in-app_purchasing/part_3_-_purchasing_consumable_products) on how to buy consumables products.

Everything was going great until I tried to get the transaction receipt returned by apple. Everytime I access this property from the SKPaymentTransaction object (anywhere in my project), I get this error which according to some people is a memory leak. This just happens whenever I access this property (SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt).

The error:

```
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

My code looks a lot like the one found on the guide I previously told you about. First of all I created a in app purchase manager which is the one in charge of making requests to apple in order to obtain product information (this works great), and update my UI whenever a transaction is succeeded or failed:

```
public class InAppPurchaseManager : SKProductsRequestDelegate
{
    IMobileServiceTable receiptTable = AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable("Receipt");

    public InAppPurchaseManager ()
    {
        SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.AddTransactionObserver (new TransactionObserver(this));
    }

    public void RequestProductData (List<NSString> productIds)
    {
        var array = new NSString[productIds.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < productIds.Count; i++) {
            array[i] = productIds[i];
        }
        NSSet productIdentifiers = NSSet.MakeNSObjectSet<NSString>(array);
        var productsRequest = new SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers);
        productsRequest.Delegate = this; // for SKProductsRequestDelegate.ReceivedResponse
        productsRequest.Start();
    }

    public override void ReceivedResponse (SKProductsRequest request, SKProductsResponse response)
    {
        SKProduct[] products = response.Products;
        NSDictionary userInfo = null;
        if (products.Length > 0) {
            NSObject[] productIdsArray = new NSObject[response.Products.Length];
            NSObject[] productsArray = new NSObject[response.Products.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < response.Products.Length; i++) {
                productIdsArray[i] = new NSString(response.Products[i].ProductIdentifier);
                productsArray[i] = response.Products[i];
            }
            userInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (productsArray, productIdsArray);
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName ("InAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification", this, userInfo);
    }

    public override void RequestFailed (SKRequest request, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" ** InAppPurchaseManager RequestFailed() " + error.LocalizedDescription);
    }

    public void PuchaseProduct (SKProduct product)
    {
            SKPayment payment = SKPayment.PaymentWithProduct (product);
            SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.AddPayment (payment);
    }

    public void CompleteTransaction (SKPaymentTransaction transaction)
    {
        var productId = transaction.Payment.ProductIdentifier;
        // Register the purchase, so it is remembered for next time
        FinishTransaction(transaction, true);
    }

    public void FinishTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction transaction, bool wasSuccessful)
    {
        // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
        SKPaymentQueue.DefaultQueue.FinishTransaction(transaction);
        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool()) {
            NSDictionary userInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(new NSObject[] {transaction},new NSObject[] {new NSString("transaction")});
            if (wasSuccessful) {                    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName (new NSString("InAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSuccedeedNotification"), this, userInfo);
            } else {
                // send out a notification for the failed transaction
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName (new NSString("InAppPurchaseManagerTransacionFailedNotification"), this, userInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FailedTransaction (SKPaymentTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (transaction.Error.Code == 2) // user cancelled
            Console.WriteLine("User CANCELLED FailedTransaction Code=" + transaction.Error.Code + " " + transaction.Error.LocalizedDescription);
        else // error!
            Console.WriteLine("FailedTransaction Code=" + transaction.Error.Code + " " + transaction.Error.LocalizedDescription);
        FinishTransaction(transaction,false);
    }
}}
```

On the method FinishTransaction I would like to insert the returned receipt in my server (before insert, of course verify it against apple servers) if the transaction was successful. So at this point I need to access SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt, encode this receipt to base64, and send it to my server. This just does not work and I dont know why.

My transaction observer:

```
public class TransactionObserver : SKPaymentTransactionObserver
{
    private InAppPurchaseManager iap;

    public TransactionObserver (InAppPurchaseManager manager) : base()
    {
        iap = manager;
    }

    public override void UpdatedTransactions (SKPaymentQueue queue, SKPaymentTransaction[] transactions)
    {
        foreach (SKPaymentTransaction transaction in transactions)
        {
            switch (transaction.TransactionState)
            {
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
                iap.CompleteTransaction (transaction);
                break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
                iap.FailedTransaction(transaction);
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So, another info I can give you is that my project compiles, and when it tries to deploy the app to my device, it crashes.

Also, I am on the xamarin beta channel since I am already using async and await.

So please if you see anything wrong let me know.

**UPDATE**

Everytime i clean the project it works, and stops giving that error!!! I dont know why this is behaving like this!

Comment: I see some methods that are marked as `async`, but they don't seem to `await` anything (such as `FinishTransaction`). Do you see some warning messages about that? (I don't think this will fix your issue, though)

Comment: yes, thats because I was previously making a request to windows azure mobile services. But you're tight it doesn't fix this issue. @jonathanpeppers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12164).

There is also a [workaround](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12164#c11) in the bug report: add "-f" to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options page.